# Amazon AWS: download amazon volume backup locally

Tags: amazon-web-services, download, backup

i want to download backup of an attached  volume on amazon locally
i  tried a backup but the restore option is to another instance that's all.
i don't have ftp installed so i cant download it this way

so my question how can this be done to have a backup locally,

Thankyou

Comment: Are you referring to an Amazon EBS volume that is attached to an Amazon EC2 instance? The normal backup method for an EBS volume is to create an Amazon EBS Snapshot, and create an AMI (which is a bootable snapshot). EBS snapshots are stored within AWS. It is not possible to download a snapshot. _Why_ do you want to download the disk volume?

Comment: yes the EBS volume, i backed it up, we are terminating the instance because we made a new website on another host by odoo,  but before that i wanna make sure we have a backup of the website in case we have missed something.

Comment: It is not possible to 'download' an Amazon EBS snapshot. You might be able to create a `.iso` file of the disk, or simply copy files off it.

Comment: can you please tell me how to copy files out of it, like code and blog and stuff like that ? we dont have ftp.

Comment: There's lots of potential ways! One way would be to copy files to Amazon S3 using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/). Then, you could download from S3 on your own computer, again using the AWS CLI. Or, if the EC2 instance is a Windows computer, you could mount a storage service like DropBox or OneDrive and copy files to it. If you wanted to do FTP, the you could install an FTP server on it.

Comment: Thank yo so much for your help, i will do that.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Because there is some chance (though rare) that these large companies may suddenly and unilaterally disable your account.